# What's the easiest way to get the SSMS stored procedure editor to recognize a view update?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

What's the easiest way to get the SSMS stored procedure editor to recognize a view update? I have a stored procedure which references a view. I added a column to the view and I added a reference to that column to the stored procedure.

The stored procedure works but the new view column reference in the stored procedure still has a red squiggly line under it with a hover message of

> Invalid column name 'MyNewColumn'

I right-clicked the db in SSMS and selected "Refresh" from the context menu and re-opened the stored procedure, but the ssms error in the editor still displays.

What's the easiest way to get the SSMS stored procedure editor to recognize this view update?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-R will refresh your intellisense. That might help.

Comment: I agree with dfundako. This is probably the most useful keyboard shortcut in SSMS. This and Ctrl+R (that hides the result pane).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Management Studio won't recognize a table exists after scripted create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201151/sql-management-studio-wont-recognize-a-table-exists-after-scripted-create)

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcuts to refresh the IntelliSense Cache in SQL Server Management Studio.

You can also refresh the IntelliSense Cache by selecting `Edit --> IntelliSense --> Refresh Local Cache`.

[image]

[How to automatically refresh the SQL Server Management Studio intellisense cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138693/how-to-automatically-refresh-the-sql-server-management-studio-intellisense-cache)